# AngularJS - POST request does not send data after first request was successfully made

Tags: angularjs, http, http-post

This is really weird. I am using AngularJS in my app. During login, I make an HTTP POST request ; data is sent properly and I receive the right response. Then I logout - which returns  me back to the login page - and I do the same http req but the data is not sent by the post request. Upon console.log I see that the $scope data is correct - just the POST data is not being sent.
If I do a hard refresh of the login page it works again. So my problem is that consecutive requests are not being made without refreshes. Here is my login function -

```
$scope.login = function() {    
        var request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: URL + "login",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: this.loginData
        });
        request.success(function(data) {                  
            var response = angular.fromJson(data);   
            if(!response["error"]) {
                sessionStorage.email = response["email"];
                sessionStorage.password = response["password"];
                sessionStorage.userId = response["id"];                
                $location.path('/dashboard');                        
            } else {
                $scope.responseMessage = response["message"][0];
            }

        });
        request.error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

And this is my logout function -

```
$scope.logout = function() {
        sessionStorage.clear();        
        $location.path("/login");
    }
```

Comment: Well this is probably a terrible answer but at the top just put var request = null; It will be to do with the promise not being resolved properly somehow.

Comment: That did not work :(

Comment: Try accessing this.loginData via $scope. i.e. $scope.loginData

Comment: Didn't work either!

Comment: What router are you using? try using that to navigate back to login page so it will trigger the proper angular life cycle destroy events  and also try calling $route.reload(); or $state.reload(); in the logout method.

Comment: @run yards - I previously had the $route.reload and I even tried using a hard redirect (location.href) in logout() - both of those things didn't work

Comment: Found it! Added header for content type and set it as application/json and it worked! Thanks for your help @run yards!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and posting it here in case anyone runs into a similar problem.
Setting a header for content type works:

```
var request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: URL + "login",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            data: this.loginData
        });
```